# HTML表示開始時にjavascriptを起動したりはできないのでしょうか。

Tags: javascript, html5, spring-boot

Springboot MVCを勉強しています。
index.htmlをHTML5で用意し、コントローラークラスをjavaで用意しました。
■コントローラクラス

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView index(ModelAndView mav) {
    mav.setViewName("index");
    return mav;
}
```

これでhttp://localhost:8080/にアクセスすると、index.htmlが表示されたのですが、
index.html表示開始時にjavascriptを起動したりはできないのでしょうか。

ボタン押下などは下記のように実施できることを確認できました。
■HTML5

```
<button type="button" id="testButton">
```

■javascript

```
$(function() {
    $('#testButton').on('click', function(){
        処理
    });
});
```

起動時にブラウザ設定言語を取得し、日本語とそれ以外でindex.htmlの表示を変えたいと思っています。
言語設定の取得は下記を参考にしたいと思っています。
http://qiita.com/shogo82148/items/548a6c9904eb19269f8c

Comment: loadイベントを使った回答がいくつか投稿されていますが、「ブラウザ言語を取得して表示を切り替える」という使い方であれば`$(document).ready()` や `$(function(){ ... })` の方が適しているのではないでしょうか？違いに関してはご自身がコメントで書かれた[Qiita記事](http://qiita.com/mimoe/items/74cb3a01a30162759fdd)の通りです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQueryを使っているなら、

```
$(window).on('load',function(){
//ここに処理
})
```

ですね。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
早速実装してみたところ、処理が実行されることを確認できました！
また「$(window).on('load',function(){」について初めて触れたので検索してみました。
　下記、参考になりました。
　http://qiita.com/mimoe/items/74cb3a01a30162759fdd

Answer (score 1):

HTMLのbodyタグの中に、onload="起動する処理"　を機銃しておくと、そのページが表示されてすぐにJavascriptの関数が起動されます。

例えば、

```
<body onLoad="starting()">
```

と書いておくと、ページが表示されるとstarting()という関数が呼び出されます。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。こちらの実装もぜひ試してみたいと思います！